# Directing Shellcode Output to a File - C

Tags: c, file, shellcode

I'm using this code from here: [Read and Execute Shellcode from a .txt File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842499/read-and-execute-shellcode-from-a-txt-file)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *file = fopen("text.txt", "r");
    unsigned char *buf;
    int length = 0;
    struct stat st;
    int v;

    // get file size and allocate. We're going to convert to bytes 
    // from text, so this allocation will be safely large enough
    fstat(fileno(file), &st);
    buf = valloc(st.st_size);
    while (fscanf(file, "\\x%02x", &v) == 1)
    {
        buf[length++] = v;
    }

    fclose(file);

    mprotect(buf, length, PROT_EXEC);

    int (*ret)() = (int (*)())buf;
    ret();

    return 0;
}
```

And I'm compiling with: **gcc -fno-stack-protector -z execstack testshell.c -o testshell**

It runs just fine but the shellcode it executes writes to the terminal, but I would like to somehow redirect that to a file.

I tried:

```
./testshell > output.txt
```

but couldn't seem to get that to capture the results of the shellcode either.

How can I capture the output of any shellcode it runs, and if possible redirect that to a file?

**Update:** The shellcode I am using, and it outputs with a sys_write syscall output to a file descriptor (It does a calculation and prints to the screen) -

```
\xeb\x4d\x5e\x66\x83\xec\x0c\x48\x89\xe0\x48\x31\xc9\x68\x33\x09\x00\x7c\x48\x89\xcf\x80\xc1\x0c\x40\x8a\x3e\x40\xf6\xd7\x40\x88\x38\x48\xff\xc6\x68\x16\x96\xd0\xd9\x48\xff\xc0\xe2\xea\x2c\x0c\x48\x89\xc6\x68\xf2\xf5\x44\x48\x48\x31\xc0\x48\x89\xc7\x04\x01\x48\x89\xc2\x80\xc2\x0b\x0f\x05\x48\x31\xc0\x04\x3c\x0f\x05\xe8\xae\xff\xff\xff\x85\xa7\xaa\xc7\x9e\x87\xa5\xa5\x8e\xb7\x87\xba\x31\x80\xe0\x55\xef\xa1\x93\x0c\x4e\x1c\xdc\x34\x53\xb3\x8b\x43\x48\x68\x30\x1d\x4b\x65\x5b\x52\x41\x4e\x44\x53\x54\x52\x32\x5d
```

Comment: This should work if the shellcode is writing to stdout and not stderr.  Try: ./testshell > output.txt 1>&2

Comment: `fscanf` format `"\\x%02x"` is redundant and misleading.  It should be `"\\x%2x"`

Comment: @Deanie No dice on the 1>&2, the output still occurs in the terminal and not in output.txt

Comment: I think he meant `./testshell > output.txt 2>&1` To redirect **both stdout & stderr** to `output.txt`.

Comment: @Deanie - I added the shellcode I'm trying to get to work if that helps.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Still a no-go on that, but thank you for taking a second look at it. I provided the shellcode I'm testing.

Comment: How does the shell code do the writing?  What is it doing?  We're not going to dissect it for you — shell code tends to be very platform specific, and you've not identified which system your using.  (Granted, it is reasonably easy to guess you're using Linux on an Intel machine, but it might be 32-bit or 64-bit Linux, and what the shell code does still needs to be understood to know how to redirect its output.  If it opens the terminal and writes to it, you'll be hard put to avoid the output appearing on the terminal, for example.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It's a sys_write syscall output to a file descriptor. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Which file descriptor?  0, 1, 2, a.n.other?

Comment: That's still up in the air. Dumping to assembly shows a call to `fprintf`, but redirecting both stderr and stdout does nothing. It's almost like a kernel printf is being used.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: that's why I listed 0 as a candidate file descriptor.  It is usually a dup of file descriptors 1 and 2, so you can both write to 0 (standard input) and read from 1 and 2 (standard output and standard error).  Of course, doing so is totally unsupported and non-portable (and you can't do it via the file streams `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr`), but then so is shell code in general.

Comment: Hah! You nailed it. `./testshell > output.txt 0>&1` worked just fine. Learning has occurred... Thanks. That is the first, and hopefully the last time, I'll run across that. I'm too old to be learning those tricks.

Comment: Thank you guys so much. Learning has indeed occurred :D

`./testshell > output.txt 0>&1`

Add that as a solution and I'll mark it correct and solved!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Glad that solved it. Let Johnathan post the answer, he left the trail of breadcrumbs for the rest to follow....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>*Transferring comments into an answer, giving credit where credit's due.*</sup>

[Deanie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3865653/deanie) said:

> This should work if the shellcode is writing to stdout and not stderr. Try:
>
> ```
> ./testshell > output.txt 1>&2
> ```

To which [user2059300](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2059300/user2059300), the OP, responded:

> No dice on the `1>&2`, the output still occurs in the terminal and not in output.txt

And [David C. Rankin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3422102/david-c-rankin) said:

> I think he meant `./testshell > output.txt 2>&1` to redirect both stdout & stderr to output.txt.

But [user2059300](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2059300/user2059300) stated:

> Still a no-go on that, … I provided the shellcode I'm testing.

Then I asked:

- How does the shell code do the writing? What is it doing? I'm not going to dissect it for you; shell code tends to be very platform specific, and you've not identified which system you're using. Granted, it is reasonably easy to guess that you're using Linux on an Intel machine, but it might be 32-bit or 64-bit Linux, and what the shell code does still needs to be understood to know how to redirect its output. If it opens the terminal and writes to it, you'll be hard put to avoid the output appearing on the terminal, for example.

And [user2059300](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2059300/user2059300) stated:

> It's a `sys_write` syscall output to a file descriptor.

prompting me to ask:

- Which file descriptor? 0, 1, 2, or another?

[David C. Rankin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3422102/david-c-rankin) noted:

> That's still up in the air. Dumping to assembly shows a call to `fprintf`, but redirecting both `stderr` and `stdout` does nothing. It's almost like a kernel printf is being used.

And I countered with:

- That's why I listed 0 as a candidate file descriptor. *File descriptor 0 is usually a dup of file descriptors 1 and 2, so you can both write to 0 (standard input) and read from 1 and 2 (standard output and standard error).* Of course, doing so is totally unsupported and non-portable (and you can't do it via the file streams `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr`), but then shell code in general is non-portable.

And that seems to have been the key. [David C. Rankin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3422102/david-c-rankin) confirmed:

> Hah! You nailed it. `./testshell > output.txt 0>&1` worked just fine. Learning has occurred… Thanks. That is the first, and hopefully the last time, I'll run across that. I'm too old to be learning those tricks.

and so did [user2059300](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2059300/user2059300):

> Thank you guys so much. Learning has indeed occurred. `./testshell > output.txt 0>&1`

Obviously, I didn't know that was going to be the solution, but when the I/O redirection of standard output and standard error failed, it became a possibility.  That behaviour has a very long history (7th Edition Unix, probably before that, too), though seldom if ever explicitly documented.